# WebView with ViewFlipper w/ one website

Tags: java, android, html, webview, viewflipper

I have some html files on my server that are displayed using a `WebView`. The html files are quite lengthy, meaning they have a lot of text (for example one is a copy of the US Constitution). Instead of letting the user simply scroll down the `WebView` to display the rest of the `HTML` file I was wondering if there is some way I could use `ViewFlipper` to "flip" to the next section of the `HTML` file's text. Basically what I mean is instead of scrolling, you "flip" the `WebView` content to view the rest of it. I am not sure if this is even possible and I apologize if what I am trying to do is not clear with my question. I appreciate any help or approaches to take or ideas on how one could do this. Thanks.

Comment: This is possible but could become complicated and maybe slow depending on the amount of HTML in the page. You will have to write a custom html parser, strip the html from the page and split it into separate parts and save it in some kind of collection. Then you can build up the separate html pages for the split content and display it in a WebView or you can create a class that will build a custom layout that will contain you parsed html content

Comment: Thanks Neil. Yeah, I was going to do that I just figured I might as well post it on SOF and see if someone had already done this. anyway, thanks for your reply I suppose I'll start doing this.

Comment: What I would do if I was going through the trouble of parsing the html is to create a layout class also for the html that will display your parsed content in your own layout. No one likes WebViews and this way you will be able to customize your layout as you feel is good and also give you better responsiveness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this two library. both are free and opensource.

[TurnJs](http://www.turnjs.com)

[Booklet](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only possible in case of responsive website's only.

Other websites can't able to scroll because the minimum Desktop resolution screen is 1024 * 768. where as in case of mobile it is as low as 240 * 320 and it goes up to 5 inch , up to 10 inch in case of tablet.